# Redirect multiple https ports to multiple external ip & ports

Tags: iptables, https

I'm not sure if this is possible or not.

I would like to accept https traffic on multiple ports (not just 443) and redirect them to external IP addresses and ports, for example:

```
mydomain.com:443 -> 2.2.2.2:10000
mydomain.com:444 -> 3.3.3.3:10001
mydomain.com:445 -> 4.4.4.4:20111
```

Basically multiple ports accepting https traffic, forwarded to external IP addresses on different ports.

I have been able to do this with http traffic using iptables but now I'm struggling to do it with https traffic. I have been experimenting with /ports.conf but I think I'm in the wrong place as this is more to do with using multiple ports for multiple websites on the same server, which is not what I want to do. I do not need any traffic to stay on the server and serve content, I just want to NAT the incoming https traffic onto its destination.

Should I be trying to do this in iptables? If so, how do I specify that it is the https traffic to redirect, not the http traffic. I've had a brief look at nginx, but I'm not familiar with it (I mainly use apache).

Thank you.

Comment: Many ISPs block port 445. So don't count on that working. As for the rest, why do you even want to use separate ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to resolve this using `VirtualHosts` in apache.

I listened for multiple http ports in `ports.conf`

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
    Listen 444
    Listen 445
</IfModule>
```

And then simply added the following to my `.conf` file in `sites-available`

```
<VirtualHost *:444>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ServerName xxx
    ServerAlias xxx
    ProxyPass / http://2.2.2.2:10000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://2.2.2.2:10000/
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I think it's better to `Listen 444 https` and/or to put `Listen` textually just before `<VirtualHost *:444>`, because whenever you delete `<VirtualHost>` you will accidentally reveal your `DocumentRoot`. Also, you most likely don't need these additional ports, your true goal is something quite different.

Comment: @kubanczyk Thank you. But the my `Listen` directives are in the `ports.conf` file not in the .conf file under `/sites-available` folder where I am specifying the `VirtualHost` for the additional ports and redirection